# SQL Server increase physical reads from INSERT ... SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

Version 1

```
INSERT INTO table_a (col_1, col_2)
SELECT DISTINCT col_1, col_2
FROM table_b b
WHERE b.col_1 IS NOT NULL
AND b.col_2 IS NOT NULL
AND b.id NOT IN
(
 SELECT b.id
 FROM table_b b
 JOIN table_a a WITH(NOLOCK)
 ON b.col_1 = a.col_1
 AND b.col_2 = a.col_2.
 )
```

Version 2

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM
(
 SELECT DISTINCT col_1, col_2
 FROM table_b

 WHERE b.col_1 IS NOT NULL
 AND b.col_2 IS NOT NULL
 AND b.id NOT IN
(
 SELECT b.id
 FROM table_b b
 JOIN table_a a WITH(NOLOCK)
 ON b.col_1 = a.col_1
 AND b.col_2 = a.col_2
)) t

INSERT INTO table_a (col_1, col_2) SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM #temp
```

col_1: varchar
col_2: varchar

table_a: clustered on primary key sequential id, non-clustered unique on col_1 include col_2, non-clustered unique on col_2 include col_1

Version 1 I/O

Table 'table_b'. Scan count 34, logical reads 118, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'table_a'. Scan count 0, logical reads 109404, physical reads 8761, read-ahead reads 7761, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(4997 row(s) affected)

Version 2 I/O

Table 'table_b'. Scan count 34, logical reads 118, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'table_a'. Scan count 0, logical reads 35454, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 5435, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#temp_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________00000044D848'. Scan count 0, logical reads 5045, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(4994 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'table_a'. Scan count 0, logical reads 105486, physical reads 331, read-ahead reads 5940, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 10412, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#temp_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________00000044D848'. Scan count 1, logical reads 52, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(4994 row(s) affected)

Version 1 is significantly slow that version 2, I assume due to the higher physical read count.

Are there any obvious reasons why the physical read count would be so different, superficially it appears as though both versions should be doing the same work.

I have ran these numerous time with hot and cold and cache and seen consistent behavour across both versions.

Comment: Query Plans http://imgur.com/a/lBpS0

Answer (score 0):

hey can you try alternate query,

--remove distince if it is not require

```
    SELECT DISTINCT col_1, col_2
FROM table_b b
WHERE b.col_1 IS NOT NULL
AND b.col_2 IS NOT NULL
AND not exists  
(
 SELECT a.id
 FROM table_a a WITH(NOLOCK)
 where b.col_1 = a.col_1
 AND b.col_2 = a.col_2.

 )
 --2nd query
 SELECT DISTINCT b.col_1, .col_2
 FROM table_b b
 JOIN table_a a WITH(NOLOCK)
 ON b.col_1 = a.col_1
 AND b.col_2 = a.col_2
```

Above all is it giving require output ?

try this way,

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [table_a]
DISABLE;

INSERT INTO table_a (col_1, col_2)

SELECT DISTINCT b.col_1, .col_2
 FROM table_b b WITH(NOLOCK)
 JOIN table_a a WITH(NOLOCK)
 ON b.col_1 = a.col_1
 AND b.col_2 = a.col_2

ALTER INDEX ALL ON [TableName]
REBUILD;
```

Comment: table_b.id and table_a.id are independent, there is not a valid join.

Comment: @MichaelCompton, now check and let me know

Comment: The plan does change, but otherall there is no improvement to the version 1. I don't think there is problem with the SELECT itself. If i run it in isolation there are no issues, it's when it is run in combination with the INSERT that the physical read explosion happens.

Comment: @MichaelCompton , there is problem in select too.you didn't tell me if output of alternate query is ok. you can enable disable your index,if perfomance of your query is very time taking and its timeout,else you can afford to ignore it. enable-disable index is not advisable.For test you can remove distinct and check the performance.

Comment: the output was the same, but I am still unclear what we are actually testing here, I really don't think the SELECT is the problem. I can run the SELECT in sub 1 second for 5000 rows, when I try to INSERT with version 1 it takes ~5 seconds where as version 2 takes sub 1 second to insert.

Comment: As an FYI I can not feasibly turn the index on/off for this operation.